# Replicate/copy tables from OLTP SQL Server database to another Reporting SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like to ask for help on how it would be best to replicate 4 tables from our OLTP production database into another database for reporting and keep the data there forever.

Our OLTP database cleans up data older than 3 months and now we have a requirement that 4 of the tables in that OLTP database need to be replicated to another database for reporting data should never be removed from those tables?

The structure of the tables is not optimal for reporting so once we have replicated/copied the tables over to the reporting database we would select from those tables into new tables with slightly fewer columns and slightly different data types. (e.g. they are using money data type for date for few columns).

It is enough if the data is replicated/copied on nightly basis but can be more frequently.

I know this is not detailed information I provide here but this is a rough description of what I have at the moment. Hopefully this enough so that someone could provide me with some suggestions/ideas for me.

Any suggestions for a good solution that would put the least amount of load to the OLTP database is highly appreciated?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have staging tables where you load new data (e.g. each night you can send data over for the previous day), then you can insert with transformations into the main history table on the reporting server (then truncate the staging table). To limit impact on the OLTP server, you can use backup / restore or log shipping and pull the data from a copy of the production database. This will also have the added benefit of thoroughly testing your backup/restore process.

Some others might suggest SSIS. I think it is overkill for a lot of these scenarios, but YMMV.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. After reading a little more about staging table it makes good sense and I see why you said truncate and not delete. The backups are written to tape using EMC Legato by our hosting provider and we don't have access to those as it is in their responsibility.  So should I look into log shipping? This is new to me so I need to keep googling. But if you have more hints for I would be greatful Aaron :)